# Допустимо ли говорить "По когда каникулы"? Или "По когда отпуск"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, неологизмы, устаревшие-слова

Можно ли говорить "по когда"? И встречается ли в литературе "по когда"?

Comment: На районе можно. Встречается ли в литературе? https://ruscorpora.ru/new/search-main.html

Comment: Это сленг и будет сленгом всегда.  Смысл понятен, но грамматика абсолютно вне нормы. В литературе может использоваться для характеристики героев и обозначения непринужденной речевой ситуации, но не более того.

Answer (score 1):

"По когда" — довольно редкое сочетание, в зависимости от контекста близкое по смыслу или к "покуда/пока", или же к "до того момента, когда". Оно не раз встречается в "Нацкорпусе", поэтому можно считать его допустимым, хотя и редкоупотребимым (судя по времени публикации работ, где оно встречается, ещё и устаревшим). Вот несколько примеров из литературы.

*Долго сидел он над раскрытой тетрадью, и мы ничего не подозревали, **по когда** красавчик Витя подошел к зеркалу, чтобы примерить новую морскую фуражку с белым верхом, то увидел, что Петя Коржик смотрит вовсе не в тетрадь, а в угол комнаты, где нет ничего, кроме электрического провода, белых роликов и черного штепселя. [Давид Дар. Богиня Дуня и другие невероятные истории (1964)]*

***По когда** Гаварсаки уходил, он тоже вздыхал и безнадежно качал головой. [К. Г. Паустовский. Повесть о жизни. Время больших ожиданий (1958)]*

***По когда** трактор попробовал взять его, гусеницы заскрежетали по обледенелой земле, и, увлекаемый тяжестью пушки, он медленно сполз вниз. [Г. Я. Бакланов. Южнее главного удара (1957)]*

*Не всегда удавалось убить его, потому что ружье бывало заряжено немелкою дробью; **по когда** удавалось ― радость была большая. [С. Т. Аксаков. Записки ружейного охотника Оренбургской губернии (1852)]*

*Сонъ во время сильной качки бываетъ большею частію невозможенъ; **по когда** утомленіе возьметъ свое, трудно передать прелесть грёзъ и мечтаній, которыя порхаютъ вокругъ васъ. [А. В. Дружинин. Письма иногороднего подписчика о русской журналистике (1850)]*

**ВЫВОД**

Употреблять "по когда" в письменной и устной речи не возбраняется. Впрочем, надо учитывать, что данное выражение встречается редко, и потому существует риск, что не каждый сможет понять, что вы имеете в виду, говоря "по когда" — хотели ли вы сказать "покуда", "пока" или "до того момента, когда".

Comment: Скорее всего, это нераспознавание буквы Н и замена её на П. Введите, например, в поиск это предложение: *Но когда Гаварсаки уходил, он тоже вздыхал и безнадежно качал головой.*

Comment: Вы по контексту не видите, что это просто ошибки распознавания?

Comment: Разумеется. Чтобы правильно пользоваться Нацкорпусом, надо знать его недостатки и особенности

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание, что все, приведенные выше, примеры это ошибки распознавания текста. В Яндексе в первых примерах "По когда" встречается реже, чем "Но когда"; Аксаков 5 ссылок все с НО, Дружинин (с ятями) 1 ссылка и она с ПО. То есть в литературе нет достоверных подтверждений использования "по когда".
Ваше "по когда" - это скорее доколе, до какого числа, когда кончается. Хотите, чтобы Вас понимали - не говорите "по когда".